# BufferedReader cannot find file in Android project

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I was having a problem where I couldn't read in a file in Android and found that it was because the file could not be located.  I have now created a bare bones program:

```
public class LoginView extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginpanel); 
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ReadingTest rt = new ReadingTest();
        }
    });
}
```

ReadingTest.java

```
public class ReadingTest {

private BufferedReader br;

public ReadingTest () {
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("profiles"));
        System.out.println("BufferedReader was successful...");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("BufferedReader was unsuccessful...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This program should read the profiles file which I have placed in the same place as the AndroidManifest.xml file, i.e. in the project root.  The program prints whether it was successful or not, and unfortunately it's printing unsucessful.  Can someone tell me where to place the file and how to access it via the BufferedReader?  My whole java project which I am trying to port relies on reading and writing to files so I can't progress until this is done.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  Ok, after doing some more research I can open my file in my main activity!! I placed the profiles.txt file in the res/raw folder in my main activity I wrote the following code:

```
is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.profiles);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

For some reason my BufferedReader can read the file in the main activity, but if I try to create a BufferedReader using the same code in a separate class, and then proceed to try to call said class it shuts down the the VM and comes up with a FATAL EXCEPTION: main in the logcat.  Any ideas how I can change the above code to make it work?

Comment: "This program should read the profiles file which...(rest of the nonsens)"  ... you should read about android basics first ... you can read files from assests folder of apk(apk is zip) you can't write there ...

Comment: Sorry, "read" was the wrong word to use; I meant it tries to create a connection to it.  I'm not sure exactly what you are saying:  I have tried placing it the assests folder and it did not work.  In this example I am not trying to write to it either.

Comment: did you tired npinti answer? at your edit: i think it's not runtime error but you can't compile the source 'this.getResources()' => 'this' have to be Activity or at least Context so if you not extending this classes in your 'separate class' it will not work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [Assets](http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/17/using-assets-in-android/)?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you just call it too fast and the file is not loaded yet. Play with Thread.sleep() before calling ready() on the stream. Maybe a some-milliseconds blocking is just normal for File I/O.

Comment: it seems like you dont now what im talking about.